# Facebook Graph API get friends statuses

Tags: php, apache-flex, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm still new to developing FB Apps (I'm using Flex), I only know how to get the user status, but the app I currently working on need to get user's friends statuses. Can I do this without needing user's friends to approve the app? I still can't find how to to this in the graph API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Dear you just need to take the permission of [friend_status](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from user. You dont need to take the permission from the friends of users to approve the application. If the user approves the application with above mentioned permission then you can get the status of the user's friends also